# Tone inside interrupt

Tags: interrupt

I am trying to play a tone with a buzzer connected on an arduino nano pin. I have also connected a reed switch with INPUT_PULLUP on INT0 and a led. The program loops continuously (it's an environmental monitor and alarm personal project) until the reed switch is set on HIGH where a function is called and the buzzer should play an one-second high pitch tone.

```
void doorStateChange() {
  static unsigned long last_interrupt_time = 0;
  unsigned long interrupt_time = millis();
  if (interrupt_time - last_interrupt_time > 1000)
  {
    led_B_state   = !led_B_state;
    digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led_A_Pin, HIGH);

    if (millis() - interrupt_time <= 1000 ){
        digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(led_A_Pin, LOW);
    }

  }
  last_interrupt_time = interrupt_time;
}
```

The interrupt is called, the Led lights up but I can't make the buzzer sound right. I 've tried with `tone(buzzPin, 5000, 1000);` but seems that the delay does not work - The sound is heard but after the 1000ms it continuous to work in a different tone (strange?).

The only way I could make it work is with `buzzPin_state = ! buzzPin_state;` where the buzzer beeps as long as the reed switch is HIGH.

I also need to say that `attachInterrupt(0, doorStateChange, CHANGE);`.

The information I get from googling this issue is gibberish: some say that delays don't run in interrupts, others call external functions etc.

What is the proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description about what you expect and what is happening with this code? You just want to pull the buzzer pin to high on a rising edge (when the input pin goes from low to high)?

Comment: I want to pull the buzzer pin to high on CHANGE for one second.

Comment: But you don't need `tone()` then, correct? (Rising/change/falling are really irrelevant in this case)

Comment: I wanted to hear a high pitch tone rather than the default buzzer (beep) one.

Comment: But that's not only the point. I can't make it to delay the tone for one second. Only way it works is if the state changes inside the interrupt function which means the sound lasts as much as the reed switch pin is high.

Comment: You might need to enable interrupts inside the function. Try placing `sei();`  at the beginning of the function.

Comment: The tone() function initializes the PWM at the frequency and determines the number of toggles that equate to your desired length. Along with initializing a the Output Capture interrupt to coincide with each PWM toggle. Where the PWM's ISR decrements that counter.Hence being inside another ISR will prevent the OCI(or PWM) ISR. Gerben's suggestion of SEI() will help. But you should really write ISR() or functions called by AttachInterrupt() not to be LONG or blocking. ISR's should be quick in and out.

Comment: @mpflaga ok got it, but I am starting to think that the whole design of this function is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do delay() calls inside an ISR. In all probability it will hang indefinitely. If you want to play the tone for a second all you need to do in the ISR is set a flag, which you test in the main loop. Turn the buzzer on when the flag changes state. Remember when you did that. When a second is up turn the buzzer off again.

In fact in your case you probably don't need the interrupt at all. Test for the reed switch change in the main loop as well. Don't overcomplicate it.